# Google Maps API v3: ImageMapType over aerial (tilt, oblique, 45 degree) imagery not lining up

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, geospatial, map-projections

I have an ImageMapType that gets displayed on top of Google's base maps. Everything lines up perfect, except when going into the 45 degree view (tilt, aerial, obliques).

I've read that in v2, there is a GObliqueMercator class that might be useful. But I can't find anything similar in v3.

I can also reproject my vector data on the server side before rendering the tiles. I'm just not sure what sort of projection should I be using to get things to align.

Anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE:
Screenshots showing the problem. It is mostly noticeable on diagonal features.

45 degree Off:

[image: Tilt Off]

45 degree On:

[image: Tilt On]

Comment: give me the lat lng that's causing you trouble

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr I don't think it is location specific, but I am using (33.664899561195,-117.89329854235001). I've updated the question to include screenshots of the mis-alignment

Comment: I think you're gonna have to draw new lines for 45 degree mode. Maybe there are formulas for that already?

Comment: I'm sure there are, I just haven't found any yet. I did find this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-api/KGMhl7t_c5w

Comment: I believe all of the coords should be in spherical Mercator in order to line up (EPSG:54004 off the top of my head), and I haven't come across any issues with mis-alignment on 45 degree so far, though I've only used the drawing library circles, markers and circular polygons. 

All circles distort to an ellipse of the correct proportion thus far though. Sorry not to be more helpful. 

I'll attempt a line and test with 45 degree later on and maybe come up with something.

Comment: The 45 degree stuff is definitely misaligned - at least when used with polygons and polylines. For now, I'm using map.setAngle(0) to prevent the 45 degree view from appearing.

Comment: Is this still happening? My Polygons (EPSG:4326) are displayed correctly - also for diagonal lines.